# Disable all client side validation in an Asp.Net site

Tags: asp.net, validation, client-side-validation

I would like to disable all client side validation in an Asp.Net web site in order to test that server side validation is correct (i.e. I want to test against people altering the response or tampering with client script)

Currently, I am either-

- Disabling JS in the browser
- Manually disabling client validation for individual validators.

Is there a global setting for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable javascript in your browser and that will help you to check server side validation. There is no global setting for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by a simple hack in javascript.

As the asp.net client side validation adds a attribute to form tag that is `onsubmit` so you need to remove it by placing the script on your master page header section.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        if (document.forms[0].name == 'aspnetForm') {
            document.forms[0].onsubmit = '';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use 'novalidate' keyword in your form tag. It specifies that the browser will not validate the form data on submission. So this will skip the client-side validation.